# Issue with absolutive position

Tags: html, css, ribbon

How can I center the wrapper? Because the ribbon menu is absolutive, its hard for me to place it responsive. Have you got an idea what I need to change to get it responsive?

This is the live example: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up7HD/)

```
body
  -nav
     -div.r1
       div.ribbon(...)
     -div.r2
       div.ribbon(...)
     -div.r3
       div.ribbon(...)
     -div.r4
       div.ribbon(...)
     -div.r5
       div.ribbon(...)
  -div.wrapper(...)
```

Comment: place the nav inside the big white div then adjust position relative to it..

Comment: when i change any position to relative, the ribbon gets destroyed

Comment: keep `position:absolute;` but use `top:0px; left:0px;` or whatever looks good. set `top` and `left` relative to the start of the big white box

Comment: Please provide the simplest possible example HTML and CSS directly here into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you've got quite an interesting design there.  You have a bunch of numbers at play.  You have the default margin on the body, you have 5em of padding on the body, and you are positioning the metal box 11.8% off of that.  To keep the nav element aligned, you need to play with all of these things.  Mixing the units gets pretty hairy unless you have a browser that supports calc.  Try this, or simplify your layout:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 5em;
    background: #333;
}
.nav {
    position: relative;
    right: calc(-11.8% + 5em + 7px);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/up7HD/6/

I'm not sure where you got 11.8% from, or why you are using 5em for padding.  Both of those seem odd as em's are relative to the font-size, which would vary from browser to browser, and even browsers with the default font changed, and 11.8% won't keep the metal box centered either, nor will it keep enough space on the left for the ribbons on very small screens.